# shrinking tables for presentations

Tags: tables, beamer, presentations

What is the most convenient way to shrink a table to fit in a beamer slide?

Comment: I'd point out that large tables are not usually a good idea in presentations, so before you simply cram in lots of numbers do think about the point you are aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Besides adjusting the font size such that it fits:

- You could use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to fit the table to the slide by using automatically expanding columns
- Or you could use `\resizebox` of the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package to scale a complete table/tabular environment to match the slide width or height.

Comment: The downside of \resizebox is that if you have a landscape page and use longtable package, the table gets flipped and is rendered useless. At least that was my case. Good tip, though.

Comment: \resizebox \r
\resizebox does not work for me; I'm using TeXnicCenter. There have to be a way to improve on including tables, none of the solutions given above work.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: in the context of a presentation, having a side-way table would be somewhat... odd.

Answer (score 26):

Use `\small` or `\tiny` after the `\begin{table}`

Comment: You mean after `\begin{table}`? Most likely, in a presentation one will use a table without putting it as a float. In that case, but `\small` etc before `\begin{tabular}` and enclose it in a group.

Comment: As far as I know the »beamer« class defines its own non-floating `table` (and `figure`) environment.

Comment: +1 also got it working adding \huge between \begin{table} and \begin{tabular}

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The problem is solved by using the following:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=5]{Title}

\end{frame}
```

Number 5 is fixed.