# How to insert a landscape normal-sized pdf page between beamer slides?

Tags: beamer, landscape

Since I have too large a table to show during a presentation, 
I would like to insert a landscape pdf page between slides.

Comment: So you don't want to show that table in the presentation, but only have it in your handouts?

Comment: Since you are doing a slide presentation, doesn't it make sense to just scale the page to fit the slide?  You can use [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) to insert pdf.

Comment: Can you use \resizebox (or \adjustbox) commands? Look at [shrinking tables for presentations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5067/1952)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a PDF landscape document (let's call it `table.pdf` for the example) containing the table and then use `\href` inside a frame to launch the table when you click on some predefined text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
And here I present \href{table.pdf}{a table}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but I fail to open it.

Comment: @justin: My example requires the file `table.pdf` to be in the same directory as the `.tex` file of your presentation. What viewer do yo use?

Comment: Is it possible to highlight the link in some way, maybe underline it or bold or blue color for links ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha you can add something like `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,filecolor=red}`
 to the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

If the existing table forms part of an external file, and you just which to include it as-is, you can use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). Here how, by means of an example.

Assume `table.tex` contains your large-format, `landscape`, `letterpaper` table (formatting provided by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and layout by [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage[landscape,letterpaper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\pagestyle{empty}% No page headers/footers
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Sequence & Wide column \\
    \midrule
    First & Vestibulum porta ultricies felis. In nec mi. \\
    Second & Nam vestibulum auctor nibh. In eleifend, lacus id tristique ullamcorper, mauris urna convallis elit. \\
    Third & Ut luctus nisi quam lobortis magna. Aenean sit amet odio et sapien rutrum lobortis. \\ 
    Fourth & Integer dictum accumsan purus. Nullam erat ligula, dictum sed, feugiat nec, faucibus id, ipsum. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now, your `beamer` presentation `beamer.tex` looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\section{Last section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is another frame}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(The above `beamer` example creates a 3-frame presentation with Table of Contents which is hyperlinked. [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to create dummy text.) Now you create your final document, `presentation.tex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
% Default beamer presentation paper size
%\newlength\beamer@paperwidth
%\beamer@paperwidth 12.80cm%
%\newlength\beamer@paperheight%
%\beamer@paperheight 9.60cm%
\usepackage[paperwidth=12.8cm,paperheight=9.6cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-2},noautoscale]{beamer}% presentation BEFORE table
\includepdf[pages=1,fitpaper]{table}% large-format table
\includepdf[pages=3,noautoscale]{beamer}% presentation AFTER table
\end{document}
```

This includes the `beamer.tex` presentation pages and interleaves the required large-format `table.tex` where needed. The disadvantage is that you loose the hyperlinking inherent in `beamer.tex`.

---

If you would like to look at ways of including the table as part of your existing `beamer` code, consider reading [Including large tables in a beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39231/5764). Three different ways include using

- scaling using `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` (provided by [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx));
- a selective column showing technique to break the table across multiple frames; and
- [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s zooming capability to zoom in on shrunken frame content.