# Including Large Tables in a beamer Frame

Tags: tables, beamer

What is the best way of including large tables in a `beamer` presentation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you please be more specific about what you want to achieve. Maybe you can add a [example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have tried.

Comment: Possibly the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/shrinking-tables-for-presentations is of interest.

Answer (score 46):

If you must include a large table in your presentation, you have a couple of options:

- Construct the table as is necessary and resize it to fit within the actual `frame` by scaling it down. This is easily obtainable via `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). In order to maintain the correct aspect ratio, specify the one length and make the other `!`. Here is a visualization:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
  \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
  \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}
    \begin{tabular}{*{27}{l}}
      \toprule
      Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
      \midrule
      One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Four  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Five  & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Six   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Seven & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{*{27}{l}}
      \toprule
      Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
      \midrule
      One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Four  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Five  & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Six   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Seven & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```
- You could break your table up into parts by only showing certain columns on certain slides. Another visualization:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
  \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
  \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
  \newsavebox{\mybox}% Store some content in a box
  \newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}l<{\end{lrbox}}@{}}% a column that Gobbles it's entries
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}
    \begin{tabular}{*{14}{@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{\hspace{2pt}}}*{13}{G}}
      \toprule
      Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
      \midrule
      One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Four  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Five  & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Six   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Seven & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{\hspace{2pt}}*{13}{G}*{13}{@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{\hspace{2pt}}}}
      \toprule
      Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
      \midrule
      One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Four  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Five  & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Six   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Seven & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

  The advantage with an approach like this is that you code your entire table the way you want to, but selectively show the columns of interest. While row-removal from a table is easy (you either comment them out using `%`, or delete them outright), column deletion is not that easy.
- Use [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s zooming capability. From the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on **11.3 Adding Anticipated zooming** (p 109):

  > Anticipated zooming is necessary when you have a very complicated
  >   graphic that you are not willing to simplify since, indeed, all the
  >   complex details merit an explanation. In this case, use the command
  >   `\framezoom`. It allows you to specify that clicking on a certain area
  >   of a frame should zoom out this area. You can then explain the
  >   details. Clicking on the zoomed out picture will take you back to the
  >   original one.

  In the above description, "graphic" might just as well have read "object", since it pertains to tables as well.

  For the sake of illustration, I've highlighted a couple of entries (in red `\alert` font) within the same table I've used before, this time also shrunk down using `\resizebox` and then zoomed in on them using `\framezoom`.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
  \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
  \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}

    \framezoom<1><2>[border=1](0pt,11mm)(4.5em,5ex)

    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{*{27}{l}}
      \toprule
      Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
      \midrule
      One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \alert{Four}  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Five  & 1&\alert{2}&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      Six   & 26&25&\alert{24}&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
      Seven & \alert{1}&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

  In the above example, the border was inserted/kept for clarity. However, by default (if you remove the `border=<n>` option), it will not be displayed. `\framezoom` has the following syntax:

  ```
  \framezoom<button overlay spec><zoomed overlay spec>[<options>](<ulx>,uly>)(<zoom width>,<zoom depth>)
  ```

  As such, I requested a zoom of slide `<1>`, upon clicking, to be typeset on slide `<2>`, adding an optional `[border=1]` of `1pt`. The zoomed location on slide `<1>` is at coordinate `(<ulx>,<uly>)`=`(0pt,11mm)` and spans an area of `(<width>,<depth>)`=`(4.5em,5ex)`.

Comment: Could anyone please explain the code that splits the table across slides (2nd option). What part of the code leads to the effect?

Comment: @Heisenberg: The column type `G` puts its contents in a box but never sets it. As such, the column entries (actually, the entire column) is gobbled/removed. You'll note 13 `l`-columns followed by 13 `G`-columns in the first table, but 13 `G`-columns followed by 13 `l`-columns in the second. So, in the first table, the latter 13 columns are `G`obbled, while in the second table, the first 13 columns are `G`obbled.

Comment: @Werner does this work with `table` as well or only with `tabular`?

Comment: @adrCoder: Both. Tables in a presentation won't float, so it's similar to just a tabular.

Comment: For me it works on a `tabular` but not on a `table`. Is the command exactly the same or you have to define something differently?

Comment: @adrCoder: You would still have a `tabular` inside a `table`... so the usage should be similar.

Comment: @Werner : Yes the `tabular` is inside the `table` but when I put the code above the table it doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the caption of the table? I will try removing it and check again.. or else I don't know why it is working for tabular but not for table

Comment: Thanks! This answer saved my day!

Answer (score 17):

The best way is *not* to include a large table in a presentation.

You show a slide for a minute or two.  How many numbers could your audience read from it - while trying to listen to your talk?  If your table is so large that it cannot fit a beamer page, it is probably too large for showing in a presenation.

You should consider changing formats: use a plot instead of a table to show the trends.  An eye can see trends in a picture much better than in long columns of numbers.

Comment: Your anwser is based on your experiences and does not offers a solution. Slides are typically written to be sefl-contained and informative at the same time, thus the need to include very large table.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to reduce it a small amount, a simple option is to drop the font size down one level.

I had a figure that the header label went off the page by a character.  Changing the table font size from `\normal` to `\small` improved this.  Just be careful not to go too small.  In this case, I was using the default beamer font size which is generously large.  As @Boris points out, you should avoid showing extremely large tables.