# Auto break wide table vertically, not horizontally

Tags: tables

Haha... I have a **wide** table (not **longtable**) that is very wide in width (many columns),

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
---------------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
```

Now, I am looking for a smart way to let it **automatically** be broken into two+ tables (e.g., it could be broken at the vertical position(s) according to the \pagewidth or \linewidth)

```
a b c d e f g h i j
-------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

k l m n
-------
1 2 3 4
```

Is this doable? :-)

### Edit:

For convenience, here is a tex file showing the WIDE table:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc|cccc|cccc|cccc|cccc|cccc|cc}
    \toprule
    AA & BB & CC & DD & EE & FF & GG & HH & II & JJ & KK & LL & MM & NN & OO & PP & QQ & RR & SS & TT & UU & VV & WW & XX & YY & ZZ \\
    \midrule
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:label}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about doing this manually using [Easiest way to delete a column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5764) You would duplicate the code of the table, but just change the columns to be kept/removed. Somewhat similar to what I've done in [Including large tables in a `beamer` frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38177/5764).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy if you invert the input order and enter the data columnwise rather than row wise (and your data is fairly regular, large entries would mess up the alignment. I used `c` here but you could fix the column with with `p{..}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zcolumn[1]{%
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}#1\end{tabular}\linebreak[0]\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

\begin{raggedright}\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}
\zcolumn{ 1\\ \hline a}
\zcolumn{ 2\\ \hline b}
\zcolumn{ 3\\ \hline c}
\zcolumn{ 4\\ \hline d}
\zcolumn{ 5\\ \hline e}
\zcolumn{ 6\\ \hline f}
\zcolumn{ 7\\ \hline g}
\zcolumn{ 8\\ \hline h}
\zcolumn{ 9\\ \hline i}
\zcolumn{10\\ \hline j}
\zcolumn{11\\ \hline k}
\zcolumn{12\\ \hline l}
\zcolumn{13\\ \hline m}
\zcolumn{14\\ \hline n}
\zcolumn{15\\ \hline o}
\zcolumn{16\\ \hline p}
\zcolumn{17\\ \hline q}
\zcolumn{18\\ \hline r}
\zcolumn{19\\ \hline s}
\zcolumn{20\\ \hline t}
\zcolumn{21\\ \hline u}
\zcolumn{22\\ \hline v}
\zcolumn{23\\ \hline w}
\zcolumn{24\\ \hline x}
\zcolumn{25\\ \hline y}
\zcolumn{26\\ \hline z}\unpenalty
\end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, if given an existing big table, it could be cumbersome to type them all over again in this way.

Comment: @Daniel you can't win 'em all:-)

Comment: Ah, yes, maybe I can use excel to transpose it!

Comment: My problem is that my table is *technically* square. And symmetric. So transposing it would have not effect.

Comment: Isn't really any way to automatically break a table??? So disappointing!

Comment: @BehnazChangizi try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables/93810#93810