# How do I fit this table to the frame in Beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

```
\documentclass{Beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
Band &   &  \\
\hline
Total stop band & No propagation possible & All of the incident field is reflected back  \\ % inserting body of the table
Partial stop band & Propagation possible for some directions & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves  \\
Pass band & Propagation possible in all directions & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that will compile. Your code does not compile.

Comment: You have two choices: you can shrink it or break it into smaller chunks.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/including-large-tables-in-a-beamer-frame?rq=1

Comment: If a table must be squeezed to fit on a slide, it may have too much information for your talk. Your audience may be trying to read it just when you want them listening to you. Perhaps you can summarize it and refer them to a place where they can read the details.

Comment: I doubt this is the case, but quite often, the `microtype` package can save some space by using micro-typographic changes (slight adjustments of the kernel, of the space, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities (as stated John Kormylo in his comment):

1. reduce font size to `tiny`
2. reduce font size to `small` and instead `tabular` use for example `tabularx` which broke lines and reduce `\tobcolsep` to 3pt.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{Beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

        \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}\tiny
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l l@{}}
    \toprule
Band &   &  \\
    \midrule
Total stop band
    & No propagation possible
        & All of the incident field is reflected back   \\
Partial stop band
    & Propagation possible for some directions
        & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves      \\
Pass band
    & Propagation possible in all directions
        & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption: case 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}l LL@{}}
    \toprule
Band &   &  \\
    \midrule
Total stop band 
    & No propagation possible 
        & All of the incident field is reflected back   \\
Partial stop band 
    & Propagation possible for some directions 
        & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves      \\
Pass band 
    & Propagation possible in all directions 
        & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table caption: case 2}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find this way to solve your problem, just add the adjust box package in your preamble and copy the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
Band &   &  \\
\hline
Total stop band & No propagation possible & All of the incident field is reflected back  \\ % inserting body of the table
Partial stop band & Propagation possible for some directions & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves  \\
Pass band & Propagation possible in all directions & Some/all energy converted to Bloch waves \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```